# Creating a batch file as a mid point between file and application

Tags: batch-file, command-line

Recently I was hit by a virus and had to reformat (a much longer story but I'll spare you the details) and it got me thinking about my own information security and I have decided that I want to make regular backups and encrypt them. Easy enough right.

But then I got thinking and decided I want all files on my computer to be encrypted, and then when I double click the file, they get decrypted on the fly, and open in the relevant application.

Ideally I would like to use a batch file due to it being native and I don't particularly want to install anything unecessary. have been experimenting with batch file.

From what I understand, you can open a file in an application using a batch file by executing something like `start Notepad.exe "path to text file\test.txt"` or something to that effect (I currently do not have a reference to that at the moment) but my main question is:

Is there a way to construct a batch file that will load the file in the designated application WITHOUT having to specify a path / with it retrieving the path from the file itself rather than being specified?

I know this is pretty convoluted and if some clarity is required, let me know.

BTW, operating system is Windows 7 Home, thought I should mention that.

Answer (score 1):

This is already built into Windows. Type encryption in Help (and bitlocker for disk based encryption). Encryption only helps on stolen computers. If they hack into your account then they have access to encrypted stuff.

Comment: Sadly, being Windows 7 home, I don't have bitlocker available to me. I was hoping to use a third party encryption tool that I could have tighter control over encryption technique and key file. The fact of the matter still stands regarding batch file opening any file without specifying a path/

Comment: There is two encryption methods in Windows. Disk based (bitlocker) and standard NTFS based file encryption. Right click file or folder - Properties - Advanced tab - and you can compress or encrypt.

Comment: Your question about paths is not valid. You can rephase it as "how do I open a file without specifing it", which is nonsensical. If you have a problem specify the problem rather than your non soloution to it.

Comment: I agree it is a little bit of a convoluted question. I think I would like to rephrase my question (and I'll update it here if I can figure out how to edit it), is it possible to use a batch file as the default file to open for a given file type, to then use it the batch file to open the desired application without explicitly stating a path, or is this beyond a batch file's capability?

Comment: Just to add, my ideal scenario is to have all files on my hard drive encrypted so if they are stolen, they are fully encrypted. I would then double click any of them to run them through batch encryption and open in the correct application with no additional effort on my behalf. From what I can tell, this is possible by explicitly stating the path within the batch file but I'm aiming to be able to apply that to any file.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is replace all the Open Commands in the registry, that will work for most but not all files. In the registry Open Command %1 is the file clicked (same as in a batch file).

Try

```
assoc
```

and

```
assoc .txt
```

then

```
ftype txtfile
```